# Makes it any sense to declare RValue methods (e.g. void operation() &&;) virtual C++1x

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, rvalue-reference, rvalue

This is maybe somewhat exotic: 
(I´m working on my update to the new c++ standard )
Is there any case that makes sense to declare a RValue Method in a class
e.g. `void operation() &&;` `virtual`? I can not imagine, because the operation
is only applicable to temporary objects, e.g. `Base().operation()` or `Derived().operation()` or something like `createObject().operation()`.
The Expression `createObject()` must return an object and 
not a reference nor a pointer, because they must both 
refere to an lvalue object.
And because of type slicing, always `Base::operation()` is called.
If you have an object of `Derived()`, `Derived::operation()` is called,
nevertheless it is virtual in `Base` or not.
So, is there a case to understood for me, that I´ve overseen?
thanks for inspiration!

Oh yes, I forgot, there are casts to RValue: move and forward! 
thanks for that!

My findings are:
1. to call a RValue reference qualified 
operation (rqOp() &&), we always have to use std::forward<..>
with the exception: Derived().rqOp();
2. it makes sense to declare RValue reference qualified 
operations virtual

Because of the following:
Given the classes Base and Derived 
with an overloaded reference qualified operation rqOp() 
and a non reference qualified one called op():

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual
    void rqOp() &&;
    virtual void rqOp() &;
    virtual void op();

};
class Derived : public Base{
public:
    //virtual
    void rqOp() &&; //override;
    virtual void rqOp() & override;
    virtual void op() override;
};
```

and an overloaded function:

```
void callOperationF(Base& b){
    cout << "callOperationF(Base& b)" << endl;

    cout << "b.rqOp();" << endl;
    b.rqOp();
}
void callOperationF(Base&& b){
    cout << "callOperationF(Base&& b)" << endl;

    cout << "b.rqOp();" << endl;
    b.rqOp();

    cout << "std::forward<Base&&>(b).rqOp();" << endl;
    std::forward<Base&&>(b).rqOp();

    cout << "std::forward<Base&&>(b).op();" << endl;
    std::forward<Base&&>(b).op();
}
```

and some calls to that overload:

```
cout << "== Derived d;" << endl;
Derived d;

cout << endl;
cout << "== callOperationF(d);" << endl;
callOperationF(d);

cout << endl;
cout << "== callOperationF(Derived());" << endl;
callOperationF(Derived());
```

results in an output:

```
== Derived d;

== callOperationF(d);
callOperationF(Base& b)
b.rqOp();
Derived::rqOp() &

== callOperationF(Derived());
callOperationF(Base&& b)
b.rqOp();
Derived::rqOp() & ===> 1
std::forward<Base&&>(b).rqOp();
Derived::rqOp() && ===> 2
std::forward<Base&&>(b).op();
Derived::op()
```

As we can see, to call a RValue reference qualified 
operation (rqOp() &&), we need to use forward<..>
At ===> 1 not the RValue qualified is called!
because b is an LValue Expression. 
At ===> 2 With std::forward<..> the correct Method
is called and also
the not reference qualified operation (op()) is
correct called with std::forward<...>. 
If we change the Interface and 
overload op() reference qualified, it will still
call the correct method, the RValue reference qulified one.

With a templatized function, like this:

```
template<class T>
void callOperationT(T&& t){
    cout << "callOperationT(T&& t)" << endl;
    cout << "t.rqOp()" << endl;
    t.rqOp();
    cout << "std::forward<T>(t).rqOp();" << endl;
    std::forward<T>(t).rqOp();
    cout << "std::forward<T>(t).op();" << endl;
    std::forward<T>(t).op();
}
```

and some calls to this function, with the Derived d above:

```
cout << endl;
cout << "== callOperationT(d);" << endl;
callOperationT(d);

cout << endl;
cout << "== Base& bRef = d;" << endl;
Base& bRef = d;
cout << "== callOperationT(move(bRef));" << endl;
callOperationT(move(bRef));

cout << endl;
cout << "== callOperationT(Derived());" << endl;
callOperationT(Derived());
```

results in an output:

```
== callOperationT(d);
callOperationT(T&& t)
t.rqOp()
Derived::rqOp() &
std::forward<T>(t).rqOp();
Derived::rqOp() &
std::forward<T>(t).op();
Derived::op()

== Base& bRef = d;
== callOperationT(move(bRef));
callOperationT(T&& t)
t.rqOp()
Derived::rqOp() &
std::forward<T>(t).rqOp();
Derived::rqOp() && ===> 3
std::forward<T>(t).op();
Derived::op()

== callOperationT(Derived());
callOperationT(T&& t)
t.rqOp()
Derived::rqOp() &
std::forward<T>(t).rqOp();
Derived::rqOp() &&
std::forward<T>(t).op();
Derived::op()
```

with the same finding: to call a RValue reference qualified 
operation (rqOp() &&), we need to use forward<..>
At ===> 3 Base::rqOp() && would be called, if rqOp 
were not virtual.

Thank you!

Comment: What about something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94981302d52f0ca9), where you `move` a reference to `base` and invoke the rvalue ref qualified member on that? In any case, why bother preventing this?

Answer (score 1):

> I can not imagine, because the operation is only applicable to temporary objects

Not necessarily. An rvalue ref-qualified function requires that the object be bound to an rvalue reference. That is, you can have a function which returns an rvalue reference to `Base` but for which the dynamic type is `Derived`:

```c++
struct Base {
    virtual void f() && { std::cout << "Base\n"; };
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    void f() && override { std::cout << "Derived\n"; }
} child;

Base&& Get() {
    return std::move(child);
}

int main() {
    Get().f(); // Derived
}
```

Comment: “An rvalue ref-qualified function requires that the object be an xvalue (as opposed to a prvalue).” What?

Comment: @T.C. What sounds unreasonable? The OP thinks only a temporary (aka prvalue) can be used to call an rvalue ref member function when really it can be any xvalue (`std::move(x)`) *or* pvalue `T()`.

Comment: @T.C. presumably he means that the rvalue ref-qualified function may be called on an xvalue

Answer (score 1):

The place I've had use for it is to make a `unique_ptr` copy-or-move function in the base class that is implemented by derived classes:

```
class Base {
    ... whatever else
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> mkuniq() && = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> mkuniq() const & = 0;


class Derived : public Base
    ...
    std::unique_ptr<Base> mkuniq() && { return std::make_unique<Derived>(std::move(*this)); }
    std::unique_ptr<Base> mkuniq() const & { return std::make_unique<Derived>(*this); }
```

This allows me to write other functions that take a `Base &&` as an arugment and turn in into a `unique_ptr<Base>` at some point if desired.  Said function can then be called with an unnamed `Derived` temporary.  Of course, lots of calls to `std::move` are needed to keep turning the named rvalue references back into unnamed rvalue refences, but that is expected when dealing with rvalue references.